# How to rebuild openssh 5.2p1 after changing configure.ac

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, openssh

I needed to add `AM_PATH_CHECK` to configure.am I then try to run the usual sequence of autotools commands to rebuild all the makefiles and whatnot:

```
aclocal
automake -ac
autoheader
autoreconf
./configure
make
```

and here my lack of understanding of autotools showes up because this release of openssh has no Makefile.am??? now what do I do?

if i try to ignore this and build anyway configure dies with this lovely error:

```
checking whether OpenSSL's PRNG is internally seeded... yes
./configure: line 18275: syntax error near unexpected token `PROG_LS,'
./configure: line 18275: `OSSH_PATH_ENTROPY_PROG(PROG_LS, ls)'
```

caused by this line in configure.ac:

```
OSSH_PATH_ENTROPY_PROG(PROG_LS, ls)
```

Is this actually caused by my changes to configure.ac?
what can I do to regenerate the required files to allow configure to work?
if i take my changes out and dont run aclocal then it works???

Comment: Run 'autoreconf' *instead* of 'aclocal && autoheader && autoconf && automake', not after.

Answer (score 0):

Check where is the .m4 file where `OSSH_PATH_ENTROPY_PROG` is defined, then pass its directory to `aclocal`:

```
aclocal -I <directory>
```

If it doesn't have Makefile.am, just skip the `automake` command.

Answer (score 0):

The `OSSH_PATH_ENTROPY_PROG` macro is defined in the `aclocal.m4` bundled in openssh tarball, and is overwritten by `make`'s calling to libtoolize.

To work around this, create an `m4` folder and move `aclocal.m4` into it. Then execute

```
aclocal -I m4
autoheader
autoreconf
./configure
make
```